# JXErrorPane without stacktrace

Tags: java, exception, swingx

while looking for a simple way to display errors I've found SwingX

Currently I'm using

`JXErrorPane.showDialog(null, new ErrorInfo("Error", e.getMessage(), null, null, exception, ErrorLevel.SEVERE, null));`

which results in the following : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a6jP.png

I really like the way this looks but I don't want to show the stack trace. I've tried passing null instead of the exception but that way I don't get the details.

Is there any way to just omit the stack trace?
(Like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zmos.png)

Comment: hmm ... not quite understand your problem: if not the stacktrace, what _do_ you want to show?

Comment: Sorry, basically I want to hide the strack trace part of the stack trace, if that makes sense http://i.imgur.com/kObaH.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like the auto-built details message (which is built by the BasicErrorPaneUI, have a look at its getDetailsAsHtml), you can pass-in a custom one like:

```
    Exception e = new NullPointerException("something ...");
    // copied from BasicErrorPaneUI
    StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer("<html>");
    html.append("<h2>" + "Error" + "</h2>");
    html.append("<HR size='1' noshade>");
    html.append("<div></div>");
    html.append("<b>Message:</b>");
    html.append("<pre>");
    html.append("    " + e.toString());
    html.append("</pre>");
    html.append("<b>Level:</b>");
    html.append("<pre>");
    html.append("    " + ErrorLevel.SEVERE);
    html.append("</pre>");
    html.append("</html>");

    ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo("Error", e.getMessage(), 
            html.toString(), null, e, ErrorLevel.SEVERE, null);
    JXErrorPane.showDialog(null, errorInfo);
```

If you want to do that more often, I would suggest a custom ErrorInfo subclass

Comment: @Shishigami glad it helped - you might consider to accept this answer :-)